# svg rendering issue when updating plot

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 plot where I want to dynamically change some of the points. Here is what the plot looks like before I change anything:

[image]

now if I go into the chrome console and try to change any of the circle properties (or removing it from the DOM), e.g. `$($0).attr("r", "20")` I get a square/box appearing over my plot, which disappears if I zoom in/out of the browser window or resize the browser window. 
[image]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?
In order to help debug I just copied the svg html (generated by d3) and posted it to [codepen](http://codepen.io/Volvox/pen/JAbnL) . I set up a click event to illustrate the problem, so click on any of the points to see the bug.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: I did include the code I'm using to update the plot — I'm simply writing `$($0).attr("r", "20")` in the chrome console

Comment: Well yes, but what's the code you're using to generate the plot? Does that append any rectangles that would show up then? Is there something else that may trigger this?

Comment: I just updated the question to include a gist link

Comment: Could it be something to do with the brushing?

Comment: What brushing ? Can you point me to the line #'s in question?

Comment: There's a comment in line 360 that suggests that some brushing is going on.

Comment: that's actually a vestige from some brushing that has since been deleted, so no brushing is taking place in the pasted code.

Comment: Looking at your codepen (which removes all script except the click handler to change the circle radius), this appears to be a performance issue unrelated to d3.  It's also specific to Chrome (possibly webkit too), Firefox is fine.  Chrome is recognizing the square that requires repaint but is just blanking it out instead of repainting it (if you resize the iframe to force a repaint, everything displays as expected).  You might want to search Chrome bugs to see if you can find anything similar.